# iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios8, app-store, xcode6.1.1

Please suggest me.How to solve this.

I got this reason from iTunes Store**"iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution"**
But I built in only for iPhone.[image]

Comment: Any one know about this.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of my question.But i didn't change anything in my code.I submitted the same build to the AppStore.App store is accepted my same binary,This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if your app is running in iPhone resolution on iPad, embed this code in you opening view controller class:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

If your app is displayed in iPhone resolution, you will see this in the output console:

> width = 320.000000, height = 480.000000

I had the same app rejection reason and it turned out that in FACT my app WAS in iPhone resolution on the iPad, but in iPhone 4 resolution (which I didn't design it for) which made it look like it was in iPad resolution even though it wasn't. Apple has dropped support for the iPhone 4 with iOS 8 and will likely drop support for iPhone 4S with iOS 9, so I neglected to design the app for iPhone 4 which meant that some of my UI elements at the bottom of the screen were not visible on the iPad displaying iPhone 4 resolution. That was the reason for the rejection (really dumb since it's not even an iPad app).

This is what I got back from Apple Developer Technical Support:

> While your app may be built for iPhone or iPod, it must still run on
>   iPad.  Did you test your app on an iPad prior to submission?  If you
>   don't have an actual iPad device to test with, many issues that lead
>   to a 2.10 rejection can be spotted by testing in the iPad simulator. 
>   I'll go over a couple of the most common ones here:
>
> 1) Controls or Important Content That Underlap the Status Bar
>
> If your app places controls or important content in the twenty points
>   below the top of the screen, they will be cutoff when the app is run
>   on a retina iPad [1].  This can lead to a poor user experience.  Make
>   sure that your app positions controls and important content below the
>   status bar.  You can use the topLayoutGuide property from within your
>   UIViewController instance to access the current status bar height. 
>   You can also create Auto Layout constraints between the topLayoutGuide
>   and your view controller's subviews to ensure they remain positioned
>   below the status bar at all times. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide
>
> 2) Authoring Your Interface Specifically For the 4" Screen
>
> Both the iPad and iPad retina simulate a retina 3.5" display when
>   running iPhone apps.  This means that content positioned 480 points or
>   more below the top of the screen will not be visible when the app is
>   run on an iPad (or an iPhone 4, and iPhone 4s for that matter).  This
>   can lead to a poor user experience.  Make sure that you have designed
>   your interface to adapt to any height.  This means either adopting
>   Auto Layout[2] or overriding
>   -viewWillLayoutSubviews/-viewDidLayoutSubviews in your view controllers to manually position your elements for the given screen
>   size.  If your app displays more content than will fit on a 3.5"
>   screen, consider placing it in a scroll view.
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html
>
> Before we continue, please try running your app on either an iPad
>   device or the iPad simulator (both the regular and retina).  See if
>   you can spot either of the above issues in your app.  If you can't,
>   send me screenshots from your tests and we'll work from there.
>
> [1]: When an iPhone app is run on a retina iPad, a 20 point black bar
>   is overlaid atop the app's window, obscuring any content underneath
>   it.
>
> [2]: To get started with Auto Layout, you'll want to watch the
>   Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X session from WWD 2012
>   https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202 followed by the
>   Auto Layout by Example session from WWDC 2012
>   https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232.